# How do I resolve this error, "ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'"?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, errors, odbc, timezone

When I run the following command I get an error, however one of my scripts requires it.

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql -p`

```
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql -p
Enter password: 
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

Trivia: [If you want to know what the `HY00` stands for (a follow up I asked years later)....](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/208615/26390)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I got this Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.

Answer (score 6):

As [kaiser](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/56626/kaiser) suggested, the trailing slash is unneeded but without specifying mysql as the database mariadb complains about a missing database. I found that

```
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p -Dmysql
```

was the correct way to solve the problem in Mariadb 164.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use MySQL on windows and get the error below

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'
```

From my [post](http://madebysql.blogspot.com/2020/08/mysql-error-1298-hy000-unknown-or.html) on how to resolve this issue:

> The issue is you do not have the time zones data installed, to install
> the time zones on a Windows machine, you will need:
>
> 1. Download "timezone_2020a_posix.zip - POSIX standard"
>    from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
> 2. Stop the MySQL service
> 3. Extract the files from the downloaded file
>    and copy them with overwrite
>    to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql
>
>    Yes, to C:\ProgramData.. and not to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL...
> 4. Start the MySQL service

Comment: Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/promotion and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer regarding links.

Comment: Worked perfectly.