# What is the HY number (HY000) in MySQL Error messages?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, errors, odbc

When I get an error some of them have an `HY` code,

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

What is `HY000` in the above context. See [this question for another example of `HY000` in an error message](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120945/2639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL reports with ODBC error numbers which include a `SQLSTATE`. `HY000` is a MySQL ODBC extension for there being no ODBC equivalent error number [from the docs on *Server Error Codes and Messages*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html)

> A five-character SQLSTATE value ('42S02'). The values are taken from ANSI SQL and ODBC and are more standardized. Not all MySQL error numbers have corresponding SQLSTATE values. In these cases, 'HY000' (general error) is used.

You can find the [`HY000` Error Codes in `error_code.h`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4f1d7cf5fcb11a3f84cff27e37100d7295e7d5ca/plugin/x/ngs/include/ngs/error_code.h), and the [full list of authoritative ODBC error codes from the Microsoft ODBC Appendix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-a-odbc-error-codes?view=sql-server-2017)

The `2 "No such file or directory"` is operating system specific.

Comment: Have a look a this book: [Pro MySql NDB cluster](https://books.google.es/books?id=zWY9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA607&lpg=PA607&dq=sqlstate+HY&source=bl&ots=jDRMdU_Bgx&sig=JQLBPCa6a99D_EkTzlc6geHru9M&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO9KPem7fbAhVnD8AKHWYiBG4Q6AEIPDAC#v=onepage&q=sqlstate%20HY&f=false), it is described as General Error (Vendor specific)